# Connecting refinery cms with Amazon S3 web services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, refinerycms

I'm having problem connecting refinery cms's web site with amazon s3 service for storing data.
I've found this tutorial on official refinerycms web site:
http://refinerycms.com/guides/amazon-s3-for-uploads

1) I'm having problems concerning keys:
- S3_KEY
- S3_SECRET
- S3_BUCKET
- S3_REGION
My question is - can I arbitrarily choose keys, or are these keys somewhere to be found in Amazon/Refinery? If later -yes, where can I found them?
What should I type for S3_REGION (I'm in Austria)?

2) After the keys are inserted, what is the next step?
Do I need to re-upload all the images on Amazon I want my site to contain?
(The original problem was - images in the site could be seen locally, but not on Heroku (where my app is currently deployed) because Heroku is read-only).
I'm missing a link how it will all function when I insert these keys.
Could someone please clarify this?

Thanks,
D.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having trouble too, and the only answer here doesn't seem to help me much. I wonder whether you've got anywhere in the past year? I find the asset_sync gem https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync helped - this will sync the assets on your dev side to S3. But I'm still having issues with image thumbnails, which I believe is the responsibility of Dragonfly in RefineryCMS. Unfortunately as far as I can tell there is basically no documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

1. The keys are in
   https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials
2. Images, files, and pages on Refinery are similar to all data in a
   Rails app: what's in your development application is not the same as
   your production app. Your local images are added to a local folder
   and referenced in your database, so even uploading them to Amazon
   wouldn't work, you'd also need to upload your database (heroku
   db:push).  Try to remember, the point of a CMS is that you don't
   have to push new code to add content like images to the site.