# Setting up Amazon S3 for Uploads and Refinery CMS

Tags: amazon-s3, refinerycms

I need help concerning setting up Refinery cms with S3 Amazon service for web uploads.
I've copied config/application.rb this code:

```
module My-Site
class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
      ENV['S3_KEY']='key-i-got-from-amazon'
      ENV['S3_SECRET']='secret-key-i-got-from-amazon'
      ENV['S3_BUCKET']='My-Site_production'
   end
end
```

(Additionally, I am not from US, so I don't know how to set up S3_REGION variable. Is there any list of regions?)

Ok - and then I've added it all to the GIT, and then i've executed:
git push heroku master.

And I thought that everython will work great, but when I've tried to make a new blog post and upload image - on the image upload window I got: 
"We're sorry, but something went wrong".

Can anyone help me resolve this problem please?
I would be very grateful, it's been bugging me for days.

Thanks in advance,

D.

Comment: Exact duplicate, by the same user. [Connecting refinery cms with Amazon S3 web services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916750/connecting-refinery-cms-with-amazon-s3-web-services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set up the region you should use: ENV['S3_REGION']='region-name', but i think this is not going to solve your problem.

To see the region name browse any os your assets at S3 and view it's properties, you will see the link url.